# Azure Data Studio failing to authenticate to github

Tags: github, azure-data-studio

How can I get Azure Data Studio (ADS) to log into github?

Last year it was connected, after I somehow input a "Personal access token".  But, that recently got messed up, and now I can't recreate the steps from last year.  Now, after opening my local folder in ADS (which was a previous clone of my github folder), I attempt to Push/pull 2 commits to github. ADS prompts that the extension wants to sign into github, which I "Allow".  That redirects me to an Internet Explorer page to "Continue", which should authorize the connection.  However, the IE browser always responds "Oh no! An error occurred! Please restart the sign in process from the editor. Forbidden"

I think I need to (re)install a Personal Access Token into ADS, but I can't figure out how.  Or, maybe there's some way to get the IE page to allow the process to Continue?

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

1. Update Git on your desktop to the latest version
2. Start Azure Data Studio
3. Select a new folder, File > Open Folder
4. Click on source control on the left pane (ctrl+shift+g)
5. Click on Initialize
6. Create a new file and add a simple script select @@Version
7. Save the file and click on the plus sign to stage it
8. Commit and add a comment to the commit
9. On github, go to settings > Developer > Personal Access Tokens
10. Generate the token save it as you will not see it again once you leave the page
11. Create a new repository and copy the link
12. Go to AzureDataStudio, in source control, click on the three dots and select ADD Remote
    13.Add Git Link you copied in step 11
    14.Add the name
    15.Add the token, you saved and copied on step 10 and you should now be able to authenticate with no errors

After the above steps, I was able to create and link new repos with no issues.
Moreover, I didn't need to use the PAT again but keep it handy and save it as you would do with a password.

Comment: Thanks - This worked, with a modification.  I was unable to "...click on the three dots and select ADD Remote."  That option did not appear.  However, I was able to access that function from the ADS prompt (<cntl><shift><P>) and searching for git Add Remote.  Additionally, another, separate window opened allowing me token - I almost missed that.

Comment: Also, since I posted my original question, I've essentially disabled Internet Explorer, with the registry setting in this posting.  That may also have allowed the window for the token prompt to become visable.
https://www.askvg.com/tip-block-users-from-opening-internet-explorer-and-redirect-them-to-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10/